# What method is used to tell the canvas to redraw its self using Skiasharp.Views.iOS?

Tags: skiasharp

**Technology**: Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin.iOS, and C#

**Problem:** I'm trying to find the equivalent of SKCanvasView.InvalidateSurface() using Skiasharp.Views.Forms to Skiasharp.Views.iOS. It appears that there is no equivalent. Below the comment in my code snippet is the method I am trying to find an equivalent for in Skiasharp.Views.iOS.

```
 using System;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 using Xamarin.Forms;
 using SkiaSharp;
 using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;

 namespace SkiaSharpFormsDemos.Basics
 {
   public class ExpandingCirclesPage : ContentPage
   {
     protected override void OnAppearing()
     {
        base.OnAppearing();
        pageIsActive = true;
        stopwatch.Start();

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50), () =>
        {
            t = (float)(stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds % cycleTime / cycleTime);

           /*
            * What's the equivalent of 
            * SKCanvasView.InvalidateSurface() 
            * using Skiasharp.Views.Forms to
            * Skiasharp.Views.iOS.
            */
            canvasView.InvalidateSurface(); 

            if (!pageIsActive)
            {
                stopwatch.Stop();
            }
            return pageIsActive;
        });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use iOS native `UIView.SetNeedsDisplay` method on the `SKCanvasView` instance. This should raise `PaintSurface` event and redraw the view.